# How do I clean RAM my app used, in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory

I working on a game that has some hitches (freezes for a bit) under certain *loading* situations.

If I start the phone or remove/reinstall the game, the hitches are there. If I kill the app and re-open, the hitches are gone which makes me believe they happen when the game assets are being loaded into the RAM. When I kill the app, memory becomes inactive but it's still there to be loaded quickly if I re-open the game.

I need a way to clean the RAM so I can reproduce hitches quickly, that is, quicker than restarting the phone or reinstalling the app.

I tried to do a [trick involving holding the wake button then home button](http://www.iphonetricks.org/trick-to-instantly-clear-iphone-ram-memory/) but that obviously only kill all apps and do not erase the memory.

I also tried to use [this project](https://github.com/Split82/iOSMemoryBudgetTest) that uses `malloc` and `memset` to clean the memory until it crashes (allocate and erase more memory until it crashes), but it doesn't clean the memory my closed game used. I have the impression that iOS deallocates inactive memory from apps that were used *before* my game, so the memory allocation app never gets the chance to use my game's inactive memory, because it's killed first.

Therefore, I'd like to understand how iOS chooses which inactive memory to use and how can I make my app inactive memory to be cleaned from RAM.

Please notice I'm not trying to find a way to *free* memory while playing, not trying to make the game use less memory, I'm trying to clear the memory the game used *after* the game is closed so the hitches happen 100% of the times I open the game.

I'm using an iPhone 6, iOS 10.3.2.

Comment: you'll have to create more than one project app that soaks up memory to push your game app memory that has been cached off the stack...  this sound a lot like how Android uses memory for closed apps.

Still using Unity?.. shouldn't be too hard to do.. just load up a few 4K textures.

Would be more interesting to know what kind of "loading situations" you are having issues with.

Comment: why do I have to create more than one app?

Comment: because, it will cache them like you've described.. if you keep trying to load the same one.. it just loads it off the back-stack

Comment: I see. But the iPhone 6 has 1GB of RAM, the soaking-up-memory app soaks 645MB, iOS and everything else uses about 150MB. The remaining memory is 205MB, and the game uses up to 580MB which means that most of the memory used by the game has to be erased by the memory app, so I assume I'd see the hitches again.

Comment: maybe, maybe not.. perhaps there is some kind of caching happening after your initial "loading", which doesn't occur again on subsequent reads... so you're only seeing this hitch on initial loads. (?)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to describe this in a couple of words. First of all I'd recommend you to review this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

If you want to release unnecessary objects manually, take a look at description of [didReceiveMemoryWarning()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621409-didreceivememorywarning) method of UIViewController

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not trying to find a way to *free* memory while playing, not trying to make the game use less memory, I'm trying to clear the memory the game used *after* the game is closed so the hitches happen 100% of the times I open the game.